# Arraylist with toString Java

Tags: java, oop

I've been trying to create an `ArrayList` with a `toString` method. my `ArrayList` is filled with Integers and I want to create 2 things. but I'm just stuck with making the `toString` method, to be honest. Down below for more!

```
class Main {
    public static ArrayList<Integer> primes() {
        ArrayList<Integer> numbers = new ArrayList<Integer>();

        numbers.add(2);
        numbers.add(3);
        numbers.add(5);
        numbers.add(7);
        numbers.add(11);

        return numbers;    
    }

    public static String toString(ArrayList<Integer> numbers) {

    }

    public static void main(String[] arguments) {
        System.out.println(toString(primes()));
    }
}
```

Comment: What are you stuck on?

Comment: What do you want `toString` to do?

Comment: @Sweeper i want to make the numbers in the parameter "numbers" to be converted in a string, alongside with a "-" between each number.

Answer (score 2):

Put this in your `toString` method:

```
public static String toString(ArrayList<Integer> numbers) {
    // numbers = [2, 3, 5, 7, 11]
    return numbers.stream()
        .map(String::valueOf)
        .collect(Collectors.joining("-"));
}
```

> 2-3-5-7-11

Comment: I think this doubles the amount of temporary memory.

Comment: if using streams: `numbers.stream().map(String::valueOf).collect(Collectors.joining("-"))`

Answer (score 2):

```
    public static String toString(ArrayList<Integer> numbers)
    {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        for (Integer i : numbers)
        {
            sb.append(i);
            sb.append('-');
        }
        sb.deleteCharAt(sb.length() - 1);
        return sb.toString();
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Do it as follows:

```
public static String toString(ArrayList<Integer> numbers) {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    for (Integer i : numbers) {
        sb.append(i).append("-");
    }
    return sb.substring(0, sb.length() - 1);
}
```

**Output:**

```
2-3-5-7-11
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to override the toString() method that the ArrayList object inherits.

```
    ArrayList<String> myList = new ArrayList<String>(){
        @Override
        public String toString(){
            String myString = "";
            for(int x = 0; x < this.size(); x++) {
                if(x == this.size() - 1) {
                    myString += this.get(x);
                }else {
                    myString += this.get(x) + "-";
                }
            }
            return myString;
        }
    };
```

To call your toString() method, just do it as normal, e.g:

```
myList.toString();
```